# UILocalNotification - Fire and Repeat at particular time each day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have this piece of code which I use for firing a local notification each day at mid night:

```
//Get todays midnight
    NSDate *alertTime = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSUInteger preservedComponents = (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit);
    alertTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:alertTime]];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    //Set up the local notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if(notification){
        //Set fire date to alert time
        notification.fireDate = alertTime;
        //Set time zone to default
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        //Repeat the notification everyday (fires at same time
        //as initial notification)
        notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

        // schedule notification
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

        NSLog(@"%@", notification.fireDate);
    }
```

However I need another local notification to fire each day at 13:00.  How is this accomplished?  I don't understand how the above code can be adapted to achieve this..

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Comment: watch my answer, there namaztimes is my array which have the firing times in it, in this code i have to fire local notoification 5 times a day (like this every day),so, according you can customise it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the time which you have to fire notification every day, you should do this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    for (NSMutableArray * arrDay in self.namaztimes) {
        NSLog(@"Alarm Array: %@", arrDay);
        int count=[arrDay count];
        if(!count){
            continue;
        }

        int day =0;
        int month=0;
        int year=0;
        int hour =0;
        int minutes=0;

        //  NSArray *arrDates=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        for ( int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            NSString * dayTime=[arrDay objectAtIndex:i ];
            if (i==0) {
                day = [dayTime intValue];    
            }else if(i==1){
                month = [dayTime intValue];                    
            }else if(i==2){
                year = [dayTime intValue];    

            }
        }
        for ( int i=3;i<count;i++) {
            NSString * dayTime=[arrDay objectAtIndex:i ];
            hour = [[dayTime substringToIndex:2] intValue];
            minutes = [[dayTime substringFromIndex:3] intValue];

            [components setDay:day];
            [components setMonth:month];
            [components setYear:year];
            [components setMinute:minutes];
            [components setHour:hour];


            NSDate *myNewDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

            [self scheduleNotificationForDate:myNewDate];

        }
    }

    [components release];
    [calendar release];
```

then from here it will connect to the main notification firing method
      `[self scheduleNotificationForDate:myNewDate];`

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)date {
    /* Here we cancel all previously scheduled notifications */
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = date;
    NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@ ",localNotification.fireDate);

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Your Notification Text"; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
    localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);

    /* Here we set notification sound and badge on the app's icon "-1" 
     means that number indicator on the badge will be decreased by one 
     - so there will be no badge on the icon */

    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: Thats my array which have different timings to fire the local notifications at that specific timings, I have already added a comment to the question to specify it

Comment: localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1; why -1? In my experience, notification set using repeatInterval doesn't show correct count on the app icon?

Comment: Who is talking about badge number here? we have talked about scheduling the notification and sound, not about the badge.

Comment: @Charan Can you please show us your self.namaztime array i'm in same trouble and trying to find the solution but stuck so please help me