# Schedule UILocalNotifications for a particular week of a month

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponent

I am scheduling `UILocalNotifications` in my project. At present I am scheduling the notification for the daily basis. Now the client has asked to do particular scenarios like scheduling for every second week. Is there a way to do this? Please can any one suggest a solution.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375128/uilocalnotification-fire-and-repeat-at-particular-time-each-day) can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Changing `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;` to `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;` (after extracting it out using NSDateComponents) will be a start.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ekeventkit store to show alert on particular dates/days etc.

You should go through [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)